# Unable to delete records in collection in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb shell to execute the command

cmd: show dbs

output:

```
    admin  (empty)
    local  0.078GB
    nutch  0.078GB
```

cmd:  db.nutch.remove({})

output:  WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 0 })

The records in collection nutch still exist.

How should I edit the command to remove all the records in the collection?

Comment: Try this `db.nutch.count()` it should return zero.

Comment: It must be zero in the first place since it reported `nRemoved" : 0 `

Comment: this is strange... yes it returned 0. but I do have a table named crawl_data in nutch that has some records. I check it with monjadb and it is there.

Comment: There are no tables in mongoDB. Where do you see crawl_data ?

Comment: In monjadb, it is under nutch

Comment: I can drop the whole database. kinda a solution for me as well

Comment: I misunderstood the structure. crawl_data is my collection, nutch is my database. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `db.nutch.remove({})` will remove all documents in the nutch **collection** of the database currently in use. It will not delete the `nutch` database.

If you want to drop the `nutch` database:

```
use nutch
db.dropDatabase()
```

If you want to delete the records of collection `nutch`:

```
use (whatever database those records are at)
db.nutch.remove({})
```